# Speed up LIKE queries without words language

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, sql-like

I have a table with 3 columns of `VARCHAR`.
I want to do a query to search if an alphanumeric string is contented in these 3 columns. Such as :
`LIKE '%whatever%'` but speed up.

I have seen the use of `FULLTEXT` indexes, it works well but only if I have words used by natural language. However, these 3 columns contain codes, references.

For example : find the reference `REF12345` with the keyword `1234`.

Have you any idea please ?

Comment: If the two(or more) component parts of a string hold meaning on their own, then it is generally a good idea to store them on their own (if you can of course). e.g. Store two columns `Prefix` (string) and `ReferenceNumber` (int), and if necessary use a [Generated Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to build your entire string. Then you can index the underlying columns and you can use `WHERE ReferenceNumber = 1234` which would be very fast with an index on this column.

Comment: Yes, but there's not "component parts" in the reference. Prefix could be any characters and the prefix is not always uses. The string can be only numbers.

Comment: Please provide some more examples of the text and what needs to be searched for in each example.

Answer (score 1):

If you added the indexes, and you need more speed -> try with *DB HINTS* (not all of the vendors have this, but mysql does) or you can try with caching

Mysql HINTS: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html

Nice article about hints: https://logicalread.com/mysql-query-hints-improve-performance-mc12/

Mysql CACHE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Hints are unlikely to be of any use.  The Query Cache has been removed in the next release (8.0).